# Kill a process inside an lvm snapshot

Tags: lvm, xen, process

In my XEN host, I have a snapshot that cannot be removed with `lvremove`

```
$ lvremove /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk -fdv
DEGRADED MODE. Incomplete RAID LVs will be processed.
Using logical volume(s) on command line
Device dm-36 (253:36) appears to be mounted on /media/snapshots/tmp-vm06.docker-disk.
Logical volume vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk contains a filesystem in use.
```

There seems to be a process hanging:

```
$ fuser -mv /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk                                                                                                               
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/dm-36:          root     kernel mount /media/snapshots/tmp-vm06.docker-disk
```

some more info:

```
$ lvs|grep docker
  snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk       vg0  swi-aos---   4.00g      vm06.docker-disk       20.44                                  
  vm06.docker-disk                vg0  owi-aos---  80.00g                                                                    
  vm06.docker-swap                vg0  -wi-ao----   8.00g                                                                    
$ lvdisplay vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk                                                                                                                    
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk
  LV Name                snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk
  VG Name                vg0
  LV UUID                xdoeHC-7PZ6-LUiZ-QKzS-QEf8-NJcU-bEpKHG
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time xen-eclabs, 2018-08-15 02:21:02 +0200
  LV snapshot status     active destination for vm06.docker-disk
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                80.00 GiB
  Current LE             20480
  COW-table size         4.00 GiB
  COW-table LE           1024
  Allocated to snapshot  20.44%
  Snapshot chunk size    4.00 KiB
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:36
```

I also tried:

```
$dmsetup remove /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk
device-mapper: remove ioctl on vg0-snap--tmp--vm06.docker--disk failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed
```

I tried removing it with

```
$ umount -l /media/snapshots/tmp-vm06.docker-disk
```

(which was only possible with `-l` because it was busy)  But that didn't changed the error message ponly there was no output with `fuser` any more. Still I couldn't use `lvremove`.

### How do I kill that process, so I can remove the snapshot?

---

workaround: I rebooted the whole XEN host (But I would rather have a solution for next time)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO fuser command only says that this snapshot is mounted on /media/snapshots/tmp-vm06.docker-disk.

Try `umount /media/snapshots/tmp-vm06.docker-disk` at first, then you should be able to remove it.

Comment: sorry, but that was my first guess. it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have to make sure that all these are true:

- There is no processes using the volume
- The volume is unmounted (`lvdisplay` should say `# open     0`)
- The lvm LV is inactive

From your question I assume the first two were done. 
For the last one, you need to do

```
# lvchange -an /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk
```

That should make the volume inactive (`lvdisplay vg0/snap-tmp-vm06.docker-disk` should have a line `LV snapshot status     inactive`). Once you do that, you should be able to remove it.

Comment: I tried `lvchange -an /dev/dm-36` which didn't help either